# Correct way to get the SQLite result in Android

Tags: sqlite

```
TextView cc = (TextView) popupWindow.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.course_code);
        TextView rr = (TextView) popupWindow.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.room_no);
        TextView tc = (TextView) popupWindow.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.instructor);

        DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(getActivity());
        databaseAccess.Open();

        Cursor qr = databaseAccess.getFaculty(inst);

        //databaseAccess.Close();

       if(qr.getCount() > 0)
       {

           tc.setText("AAAAAAA");           
           //tc.setText(qr.getString(qr.getColumnIndex("fac_name")));
           Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Fac_Code : "+qr.getCount(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
```

If I write `tc.setText("AAAAAAA");` line, then it is work, that is executing the program and display the popup and Toast with the correct value, but when I want to display the next line to get name, then it is being closed the program

The following is the Database query

```
 public Cursor getFaculty(String fc){
        Cursor c = database.rawQuery("Select * from faculties where fac_code = '"+fc+"'",new String[]{});
        return c;
    }
```

Please anyone , what are the problem and its solution. I pass a long time for this, but can not solve

Answer (score 0):

You are not positioning the Cursor and thus trying to read data from the position before the first row, which cannot be done.

As such try :-

```
   Cursor qr = databaseAccess.getFaculty(inst);
   if(qr.moveToFirst()) {
       tc.setText("AAAAAAA");           
       tc.setText(qr.getString(qr.getColumnIndex("fac_name")));
       //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Fac_Code : "+qr.getCount(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //Commented out as the issue could be a Null Pointer Exception
   }
```

P.S.

You can use

```
public Cursor getFaculty(String fc){
    return database.rawQuery("Select * from faculties where fac_code=?,new String[]{fc});
}
```

- Additionally this protects against SQL Injection

instead of :-

```
public Cursor getFaculty(String fc){
    Cursor c = database.rawQuery("Select * from faculties where fac_code = '"+fc+"'",new String[]{});
    return c;
}
```